# Minimizing a sum of sine

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $k_1$, $k_2$, ..., $k_n$, where $k_i \in \{ 0,1 \}$, $\forall i$, so that they minimize the following sum
$$
S = A_1 \sin{\left( \frac{\pi}{4}+k_1 \pi \right)}+A_2 \sin{\left( \frac{\pi}{4}+k_2 \pi \right)}+\cdots + A_n \sin{\left( \frac{\pi}{4}+k_n \pi \right)}, 
$$
where $A_1 > A_2 > \cdots > A_n > 0$ and $A_1+A_2+\cdots+A_n=1$, and satisfy
$$
S \ge 0.
$$

My best chance so far is to find the set of minus and plus so that it minimizes
$$
\sqrt{2} S = \pm A_1 \pm A_2 \pm \cdots \pm A_n \ge 0,
$$
so that $k_i=0$ refers to plus and $k_i=1$ refers to minus.

For $n=2$, it is obvious that the solution is $k_1 = 0$ and $k_2=1$, i.e, $S=A_1-A_2$.

For $n = 3$, I use $|x+y| \ge ||x|-|y||$, which results the solution $S = |A_1-(A_2+A_3)|$ and
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
k_1 = 1, k_2 = k_3 = -1, &\text{if } A_1 \ge A_2+A_3,\\
k_1=-1, k_2=k_3=0, &\text{if } A_1 < A_2+A_3,
\end{array}\right.
$$
However, I cannot proceed further from here.